# Spring @Transactional(isolation=Isolation.READ_UNCOMMITTED) vs Spring Data @Lock(LockModeType.None)

Tags: spring, hibernate, jpa, spring-data, transactional

Some systme info, it's using Spring, Spring Data, JPA and Hibernate.

My question is, what's the difference between the 2? See below:

```
//this uses plain JPA, and uses Spring's Transactional
@Transactional(isolation=Isolation.READ_UNCOMMITTED)
public List getData() {
   //code
}


//this uses Spring Data
@Lock(LockModeType.None)
public List getData() {
   //code
}
```

Comment: Well.. transaction isolation and locking are two different concepts. I think you need to revisit your DBMS book?

Comment: @Carlos Jaime C. De Leon Have you solved this problem? If you have solve it, How have you done?

Answer (score 1):

Locking and Transaction are two different things, but anyway...

This isolation level allows dirty reads. One transaction may see uncommitted changes made by some other transaction.

```
/**
 * A constant indicating that dirty reads, non-repeatable reads and phantom reads
 * can occur. This level allows a row changed by one transaction to be read by
 * another transaction before any changes in that row have been committed
 * (a "dirty read"). If any of the changes are rolled back, the second
 * transaction will have retrieved an invalid row.
 * @see java.sql.Connection#TRANSACTION_READ_UNCOMMITTED
 */
READ_UNCOMMITTED
```

[LockModeType](https://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/persistence/LockModeType.html)

> Lock modes can be specified by means of passing a LockModeType
>   argument to one of the EntityManager methods that take locks (lock,
>   find, or refresh) or to the Query.setLockMode() or
>   TypedQuery.setLockMode() method.
>
> Lock modes can be used to specify either optimistic or pessimistic
>   locks.

So, as it said LockModeType.NONE is default for annotations (JPA, annotations left and right) I guess when you use EntityManager.find(Class, Object) the default LockModeType is used.

I suggest to you [this link](http://www.objectdb.com/java/jpa/persistence/lock) to see some examples to Pessimistic and Optimistic lock, and [this link](http://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/spring-framework-reference/html/transaction.html) to see Transactional examples